# Display links in my site (from an RSS feed) using the article's title as link

Tags: feeds

I need to display an RSS feed from a different site into my site, showing the title of each article.

Do you have any idea on how I can accomplish this task?
What modules do I need to install?
How can I use the Views module to create views block to display rss link?

Comment: hi.. i quite don't understand the meaning of link block format.. but why not use optional default RSS Feed Aggregator module to subscribe the desired feed and use a combination of `theme_aggregator_block_item` function and adding styling with any of the aggregator tpls like block-aggregator.tpl.php if you wish to do it programmatically

Comment: @optimusprime619..thanks for the quick response...I mean to display the `Title` of article. Any idea how I can accomplish this using RSS Feed Aggregator? Really thanks